# Subversion Apache2.2 LDAPS authentication failed

Tags: svn, ldap, apache

OS: Redhat Linux
Subversion: 1.5.0
Apache: 2.2.17

httpd.conf:

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 200000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600

<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/svnroot/repository
AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svnroot/repository/svn_access_file
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://master.ldap.ebupt.com:636/OU=staff,DC=ebupt,DC=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)" SS
L
AuthName "Subversion.resository"
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Apache error_log:

```
[Thu Feb 24 16:48:00 2011] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(403): [client 10.1.85.181] [25242] auth_ldap a
uthenticate: using URL ldaps://master.ldap.ebupt.com:636/OU=staff,DC=ebupt,DC=com?uid?sub?(objectCl
ass=*)
[Thu Feb 24 16:48:00 2011] [info] [client 10.1.85.181] [25242] auth_ldap authenticate: user jinjian
kang authentication failed; URI /svn [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Can't contact LDAP server]
```

ping master.ldap.ebupt.com is OK.

My FTP LDAPS authentication is OK as below:

```
server:master.ldap.ebupt.com
port:636
Enable SSL:checked
Base DN:ou=staff,dc=ebupt,dc=com
anonymous:checked
Search Filter:(objectClass=*)
User DN attribute:uid
Search scope:subtree
```

Comment: SVN 1.5 is twelve years old and is not supported for years. The latest version is 1.13.x. You should upgrade.

Comment: @bahrep To be fair, the question itself is 9 years old. SVN 1.5 was only 3 years old at that time.

Comment: @VonC haha, I did not notice that. The question appeared in the list of recently active questions and I did not check the date.

Comment: @bahrep Sill, you are correct. An upgrade is long overdue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Can't contact LDAP server" can mean a bunch of things, but if your LDAP server is reachable and you're using simple bind over SSL as you are here, it means Apache doesn't trust the certificate the LDAP server is presenting.

You need to tell Apache about the certificate so that it can create the SSL connection.

This section of the Apache docs is what you need: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html#usingssltls

The best way to do this is to obtain the CA certificate from the CA that signed the certificate on your LDAP servers, and use the LDAPTrustedGlobalCert directive. An example, from one of my boxes:

```
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CERT_BASE64 /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem
```

How you go about obtaining the CA cert varies; my LDAP servers are running certs signed by our own CA, so I can easily get the CA cert. Your setup may be different; consult whoever looks after your LDAP server.

You can also obtain the certificate that the LDAP server presents using the OpenSSL tools:

```
openssl s_client -connect your.ldap.host:636 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

That'll display the certificate. Copy everything (including BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE) into a file.

Now add the directive:

```
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CERT_BASE64 /path/to/your/cert/file
```

to the top of your Apache configuration. Restart Apache, and you're done.

Comment: I download cert file by 'curl -O http://10.1.1.5:443/ca.crt', And add 'LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CERT_BASE64 /path/to/my/cert/file' to my httpd.conf, everything is OK. Thanks.
By the way, I find if add 'LDAPVerifyServerCert off', comment 'LDAPTrustedGlobalCert...', everything is OK too. LDAPVerifyServerCert directive's default value is on.